# Why is my vbCrLf not working?

Tags: html, vbscript, asp-classic

I have to declare a variable in which I need to keep multiple sentences (vbscript is the language I am using). So, I put vbCrLf at the end of sentences in order to get a break. But it is not giving me the break instead it  is giving me a whole paragraph.

```
strHtmlBody = "<div><font face='Arial' size='-1'>Greetings "& RS("firstname") &":"& vbCrLf & _ 
        "Here is the email that contains your account information to access your account at www.example.com." & VbCrLf & VbCrLf & _
        "Your Email Address: " & RS("Email") & VbCrLf & _
        "Your Password : " & RS("Password") & VbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
        "Remember, if you have any questions or concerns, please let us know, simply reply to this email." & VbCrLf & _
        "ABC Company" & vbCrLf & _
        "http://www.example.com" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
strHtmlBody = strHtmlBody & "</div>"
```

Comment: This likely using Classic ASP with VBScript as the scripting language judging by the code content.

Answer (score 0):

HTML ignores most whitespace which `vbCrLf` represents. Use `<br>` tags in its place.

Comment: It's low quality.  You can improve it by explaining more.  What is "<br>" for instance.  What is "markup" and why doesn't it respect whitespace? That's one thing.  The other thing is that I was prepared to spend a little time writing out a good answer, but since you had to be the fastest gun in the west -- sticking your "foot in the door" by submitting an incomplete answer -- presumably to get votes before anyone else, I'm questioning whether I should bother.  It's just an annoying behavior that I see all the time, so I down-voted.

Comment: I tried writing <br> but still it didn't show me any break line. for instance: "Here is the email that contains your account information to access your account .<br>" Am I missing out something?

Comment: @LouManizer are you sure you are sending an html email? are you seeing the other tags? did you use `<` or `&lt;`?

Comment: yes i am sending email and I used <, am I suppose to use &lt;?

Comment: @LouManizer make sure you use `<`. If you edit your question and post more code of how `strHtmlBody` is used, that would help.

Comment: <br> worked except for few lines. I was updating the code in wrong spot. I apologize for that. However for statement like:  "Your Email Address: " & RS2email("Email") & VbCrLf & _   Where am I supposed to keep <br>? I kept : "Your Email Address: " & RS2email("Email") "<br>" which did not work.

Comment: @LouManizer you have to combine the strings with `&`.

Comment: "Your Email Address: " & RS2email("Email") & "<br>"  something like this @DanielA.White

Comment: @LouManizer exactly.

Comment: I was missing &_ at the end of statements. Thanks @DanielA.White and all for your help